# javascript function is executed twice

Tags: asp.net

I have the code  below.onClientClick event of the linkbutton showVlaues javascript function is executed.  I tried to trace the code in the debug mode and when I click on the link button, the debuuger control is tranferred to the showvalues function and then it goes to the code behind and goes to page load event of the application and then  it goes again to the showvalues function, I am not sure why it does that, but in debug mode, I can see that it goes to both the $get lines and when I tried to see the value of dataitems, it dataitems is not defined in current context and it changes the value of showValues. Is their any way I can avoid it that control does not go to showvalues function again. I want it to be executed only once when I click on the link button.

any help will be appreciated.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head runat="server"> 
    <title></title> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       function showValues(IDValue, timeValue, minValue){ 
            var dataItems = $get('<%= PanelBar1.Items[0].Items[0].FindControl  ("Grid_IDPicker").ClientID %>')
            var lbl_ID = $get('<%= PanelBar1.Items[0].Items[0].FindControl("lbl_ID").ClientID %>');



        } 
     </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
     <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 
    </div> 
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display."> 
        <Columns> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="time" HeaderText="time" SortExpression="time" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="min" HeaderText="min" SortExpression="min" /> 
            <asp:TemplateField> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClick" OnClientClick='<%#String.Format("return showValues({0},&#39;{1}&#39;,&#39;{2}&#39;)", Eval("id"),Eval("time"),Eval("min")) %>' runat="server"> <%# Eval("id") %></asp:LinkButton> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField> 
        </Columns> 
    </asp:GridView> 
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString1 %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [time], [min] FROM [name]"></asp:SqlDataSource> 
         </form> 
         </body> 
        </html>
```

Comment: Your LinkButton will trigger a postback to the server. If you want to prevent this from happening, your showValues function should at least return false ; or you could use a HyperLink with NavigateUrl="#" instead of a LinkButton